# Get status of kubernetes deployment in gitlab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup gitlab pipeline which builds and deploys to kubernetes. I am at step where i do

```
kubectl apply -f Application-k8s-file.yaml
```

and

```
kubectl rollout status deployment deployment_name
```

as you can see i am using rolling updates. Even though kubernetes deployment failed, i see status as waiting for pod. How do i make sure that my job fails when kubernetes deployment fails.

Comment: Are you setting the `.spec.progressDeadlineSeconds` field ? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds

Comment: @EstebanGarcia - Nope. What does it do actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you're setting the `.spec.progressDeadlineSeconds` field. It denotes the number of seconds the Deployment controller waits before indicating that the Deployment progress has stalled.

This will cause the `kubectl status rollout` command to fail after X amount of seconds.

```
kubectl rollout status deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new replicas have been updated...
error: deployment "nginx" exceeded its progress deadline
$ echo $?
1
```

More information: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds

Comment: If i am trying to bring up 5 pods and it takes time, wont number of seconds lapse and it turn back as false?

Comment: You should adjust this to a proper number, depending on what is a reasonable time for your case. It's good to note that this will timeout if the deployment is "not progressing". Meaning, new pods are not becoming available. If a pod takes too long to become available but it does before the `progressDeadlineSeconds` the deployment will "progress" and the deadline will be reset. So, as long as each pod is not taking more than your `progressDeadlineSeconds` to become available you're ok, if not there is a problem that requires your attention.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/#visualize-kubernetes-resources-in-gitlab) (June 2023) offers an alternative to kubectl commands:

> ### Visualize Kubernetes resources in GitLab
>
> How do you check the status of the applications running in your clusters?
> The pipeline status and environment pages provide insights about the latest deployment runs.
> However, previous versions of GitLab lacked insights about the state of your deployments.
>
> In GitLab 16.1, you can see an overview of the primary resources in your Kubernetes deployments.
>
> This feature works with every connected Kubernetes cluster. It doesn’t matter if you deploy your workloads with the CI/CD integration or GitOps.
>
> [image: deployments status]
>
> To further improve the feature for Flux users, support for showing the synchronization status of an environment is proposed in [issue 391581](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/391581).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/kubernetes_dashboard.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/390769).

See a full demo with this video "[Kubernetes visualizations in GitLab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D90JeLMHlLM)"